# How to use offset in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, offset

How to make a delay for one candle so that the bar starts with open. Standard delay cannot do this.

[image]

[image]

I tried changing the timeframe, using a delay but none of that helped.

```
//@version=2 
study("MTF", overlay=true)
tim=input('5')
out1 = security(tickerid, tim, open)
out2 = security(tickerid, tim, close)
plot(out1,color=red,linewidth = 4, transp = 0)
plot(out2,color=green, linewidth = 4, transp = 0)
```

Comment: //@version=2
study("MTF", overlay=true)
tim=input('5')
out1 = security(tickerid, tim, open)
out2 = security(tickerid, tim, close)
plot(out1,color=red,linewidth = 4, transp = 0)
plot(out2,color=green, linewidth = 4, transp = 0)

Comment: What do you mean by "the bar starts with open"?

Comment: When we use a delay, the line should be at the opening level of the next bar (Red line).

Comment: That is, the red line on the chart should be at the opening level of this candle. Delay already applied on chart.

Answer (score 0):

Answering EXACTLY to your question:
For 1m chart, and 5m HTF, the offset will be -5. To 15mHTF: -15. Etc

For this to happen, you must [migrate your code to v5](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html)
And use technique of [No-Repainting](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I would like to ask if there are other options for solving my question, except for your option. For example, in order to be able to offset from two candles under the above conditions.

Comment: Check out this [JustUncleL indicator](https://www.tradingview.com/script/19dTAxx4-HTF-Candle-R1-2-by-JustUncleL/)